# Getting Phpunit tests working while in vendor

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

## Getting Phpunit tests working while in vendor

I have a library named `bbn` installed in my vendor directory and i want to run the tests while being a dependency.

Among the dependencies i noticed some can run without problem but others need to be the main project to be run. It is the case for the `bbn` library but i don't understand why.

Trying to achieve this i've done some changes to the composer configuration but i still get the same error of class not found.

This is how i set up my composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "bbn\\": "src/bbn/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "bbn\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
```

My tests is in a directory named "tests". In this "tests" dirctory i have another directory named "tests" (so tests/tests) in this test folder I have implemented two files containing some traits:

Reflectable.php:

```
<?php

namespace bbn\tests;

trait Reflectable
{
  ...
}
```

ReflectionHelpers:

```
<?php

namespace bbn\tests;

class ReflectionHelpers
{
    ...
}
```

In my main "tests" directory so (tests/) i have a test class implemented who call my refletable class but i got an error while running the test:

XTest.php:

```
<?php

namespace bbn;

use bbn\X;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use bbn\tests\Files;
use bbn\tests\Reflectable;

class XTest extends TestCase
{
  use Reflectable, Files;

  ...

}
```

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Trait "bbn\tests\Reflectable" not found in XTest.php
```

Answer (score 0):

When your library is installed in `vendor`, `*-dev` configurations doesn't apply. So, it's impossible to run library tests when library is in `vendor`.

If you want to run library tests, you need to load it from its Git repository and then run it's `composer install` - only in this case its `autoload-dev` will be active.

Comment: Indeed. You can read the details at https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev Also you could add an autoload-dev rule in the composer.json of the main application. Where you point the path to the correct vendor folder. 
I would not recommend this though and doe the testing in the lib itself, as Edward is also pointing out.

Comment: Another strong objection against running tests is that `require-dev` of the package is also not applied. There is absolutely no guarantee that tests in package are compatible with current environment.